# Practical application of analytic center of the set of linear inequalities

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am wondering how the analytic center of the set of linear inequalities is used in practice/real-world applications.

Comment: The analytic center cutting plane method (ACCPM) computes an analytic center in each major iteration.  Is that the kind of answer you're looking for?

Comment: No, I'm trying to understand the practical use cases, not the method. Is this only a mathematical concept that helps us to solve optimization problems? or can we think of a physical example?

Comment: It's certainly a concept used in the ACCPM and other optimization algorithms.  I can't think of useful analogy to a physical process.